# SSMS down arrow on last line

Tags: ssms

I apologize if this is not the correct place to ask this but something is bugging me. I could have swore that at a previous job I could be on the last line of code in SSMS and hit the down arrow and the cursor would move to the end of the line. Now it just stays in the middle of that last line. I'm using SSMS 11.0.2100.60. Is there a setting I'm missing or did I imagine that happening? :)

Comment: I have never heard of that one, nor is it listed here https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174205%28v=sql.110%29.aspx

Comment: I never heard about it too..

Comment: Thou art not insane, the feature exists(ed) - http://screencast.com/t/xJqrUkl7rRs7. I've managed to see it only on a SSMS 2005 (don't ask). But I've got no idea of what setting is different than my other 2012/2014 SSMS instances :/. There's nothing there that sticks the eye.

Comment: That explains it. I was using 2005 in that previous job. Damn Microsoft! I loved that feature. Go ahead and put that as the answer, @Marian, and I'll accept it and give you credit.

Comment: I think it worked in 2008 as well. Notepad++ has the same feature and it's extremely useful. Shame it's gone

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As already shown in the comments, I've seen/used the same feature in SSMS 2005 as shown [here](http://screencast.com/t/xJqrUkl7rRs7). But I didn't manage to see what ever editor window setting would be different than in SSMS 2012/2014 where the behavior has changed.

Answer (score 3):

I can affirm that this works in SQL Server 2005 through SQL Server 2008 R2 (I am not sure about SQL Server 2000). It appears to have been broken in the SQL Server 2012 pre release build, also known as "Denali".

I found the Denali information here:

[SQL Server v.Next (Denali) : The New SSMS](https://sqlblog.org/2010/11/23/sql-server-v-next-denali-the-new-ssms) by Aaron Bertrand

Quoting from item #3 under the title "The Bad" with the subtitle "Missing Keyboard Functionality":

> A very simple keyboard operation I've been used to performing in Management Studio is, in a query editor, holding the down arrow key to get to the end of the last line in a query window.  In the Visual Studio shell, holding down gets you to the last line, but it doesn't move the cursor to the last character on that line.  Not a huge deal, just mildly annoying until you get used to it.

This shortcut will be missed...

Answer (score 0):

I was finding the same issue after upgrading to 2012 from 2008. It will take a little getting used to, but you can use the End key to the same effect.